# Websphere Application Server Secure REST API

Tags: java, security, rest, websphere

I want to expose a REST API from Webpshere Application Server 8. I could be able to successfully expose a REST endpoint without security. But while adding security I'm getting 404 error code as follows:

```
[5/6/15 7:44:20:369 CAT] 00000063 RequestProces I org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor logException The following error occurred during the invocation of the handlers chain: WebApplicationException (404 - Not Found) with message 'null' while processing GET request sent to http://localhost:9080/StudentWeb/student/service/students/100
```

Please find the `web.xml` used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>StudentWebServelet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.IBMRestServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.student.rest.StudentApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>StudentWebServelet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/student/*</url-pattern>       
  </servlet-mapping>
  <security-role>
    <description>Registered Users</description>
    <role-name>RegisteredUsers</role-name>
  </security-role>  
  <security-constraint>
    <display-name>StudentSecurity</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Student resource</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/student/service/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>RegisteredUsers</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
</web-app>
```

Comment: I did come right with a solution. All my secured resource path will be "/services/{resource name}".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did come right with a solution. 
All my secured resource path will be "/services/{resource name}".

@Path(value="/secured/students")
public class StudentResource extends AbstractResource {

```
@Inject
StudentBeanLocal studentBeanLocal;
```

---

}

Unsecured resource will be something like @path(value="/address").

Answer (score 0):

you can have two servlet mappings. one for secured APIs and other one is for public APIs. 
using   authenticate the secured APIs, give the APIs path in that url mapping.

If you have a login form use the form based authentication as well.